# Getting a 'Component not part of Ngmodule' while it shouldn't be called in he current module

Tags: angular

so I am getting a problem on a new Angular app.

Based on Tour of Heroes, I created an app, with an 'AboutComponent', which is part of appModule. Added on the routes, and it workds fine.

Besides, I created a new Module. This module is also routedwith lazy load. But when I click on the nav to get to the new modules, I got an error saying :
'AboutComponent is not part of any Ngmodule or the module has not been loaded'.

I checked, and found no code that invoke AboutComponent when loading the new module. As I don't need it in my new module.

Here is the code :

App

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner.component';

import { CoreModule} from './core/core.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, AboutComponent, BannerComponent, WelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
  </h1>

</div>
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/about">About</a>
  <a routerLink="/articles">Articles</a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'articles', loadChildren: 'app/article/article.module#ArticleModule'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

AboutComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  template: `
    <h2 highlight="skyblue">About</h2>
    <twain-quote></twain-quote>
    <p>All about this sample</p>`
})
export class AboutComponent { }
```

My module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ArticleRoutingModule } from './article-routing.module';
import {SharedModule} from '../shared/shared.module';
import { ListeArticleComponent } from './liste-article/liste-article.component';
import { DetailArticleComponent } from './detail-article/detail-article.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ArticleRoutingModule, SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [ListeArticleComponent, DetailArticleComponent]
})
export class ArticleModule { }

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ListeArticleComponent} from './liste-article/liste-article.component';
import { DetailArticleComponent} from './detail-article/detail-article.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '',    component: ListeArticleComponent },
                        { path: ':id',    component: DetailArticleComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ArticleRoutingModule { }
```

I think, I am missing a little thing, as I am new with angular, but can't see it.

I also can provides you my github project if you need to, and my code provided is not enough (I don't know yet, all connections between my files soI maybe forgot some useful things for you).

**Here is the git hub project** : https://github.com/kme-rennes/dev-site-as-with-angular

Comment: can add your github project,it may help easy to understand better

Comment: Instead of creating a Router Module you can simply create a route file and import it in the app module will be easier. check this [link](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/app.routing.ts)

Comment: @RahulSingh but that is what I did : I have my routes in a route file app-routing.module, and import it in AppModule. The code in the question has not been separated in two zones (break space not handle well), but still... You can check my github to verify.

Comment: @Zaphod you have created a router module. I just want you to add a router file and export it check that link might help. Something to do with your router i guess

Comment: @RahulSingh ok. I don't really see the difference. But I tried, and I get the same results.

Comment: @Zaphod you export AppRoutingModule  (which uses AboutComponent) from SharedModule, it might cause an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `y_vyshnevska` said in the comment (saw it about at the same time), you export the `AppRoutingModule` in the `SharedModule`. This means that all your modules importing the `SharedModule` will also import all the modules from the `AppRoutingModule`, which is expecting an `AboutComponent`, while there is none in your lazy-loaded `ArticleModule`.

Here is the final `SharedModule` :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    // AppRoutingModule,
    HighlightDirective,
    TitleCasePipe
  ],
  declarations: [
    HighlightDirective,
    TitleCasePipe
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: Oh, I think I see now what is wrong. I was thinking, besides what you said, that AppRoutingModule, needed to be loaded in my Shared, while it isn't, since the only module that will need it is AppModule. And it works. So simple... Thanks (also to  y_vyshnevska)